# Deleting a non-string in js object

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following object:

```
const a = {a: 1, 0: 2};
delete a.a; // this works
delete a.0; // this errors (I suppose expecting a['0'] and not a[0])
```

Does the method deletion form of `obj.key` only allow deletion of a string key? And if it's a non-string type, is the only way of doing deletion via the key lookup method of `obj[key]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#dot_notation):

> In the `object.property` syntax, the property must be a valid JavaScript identifier.

... where ...

> ... identifiers are case-sensitive and can contain Unicode letters, `$`, `_`, and digits (0-9), but may not start with a digit.

So, answering your question, property with name `0` can be only accessed with key notation.

Comment: I see. So in that case, is the most common way to delete a non-string object using the lookup syntax? Are there other ways as well, or that's the only way?

Comment: Only using key notation, i.e. `delete obj[non-identifier]`.

Comment: And to clarify, except in the case of [symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol), *all* keys will be strings.  Just, in this case, it's being coerced from a number when you declare it

Comment: @dave I see, so even doing `{0: 2}` will give me `{'0': 2}`? I just cannot use property notation because a leading `0` is not allowed as a legal identifier?

Comment: @David542 exactly - if you do `Object.keys({0: 2})` you'll get `["0"]`.  It's only because when using dot notation the property must be a valid JavaScript identifier